# Odd flash script issue

Tags: flash

Trying to run a flash file in my page. It appears to work in FF, Chrome, Safari, but not (amazingly) in IE.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','800','height','800','src','flash/navpage7CS3','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','flash/navpage7CS3' ); 
//end AC code
</script>
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="800" height="800">
        <param name="movie" value="flash/navpage7CS3.swf">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <embed src="flash/navpage7CS3.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="800"></embed>
      </object>

      </noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your SWF files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an `<object>` tag, as in the following: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="filename.swf" width="your swf width" height="your swf height">
        <param name="movie" value="path/filename.swf"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you choose not to embed your swf files, then I found (about 3 years ago) that I had problems getting IE to pick up Flash files from subdirectories.

As a work around I had to make sure that the swf file was in the same folder as the page that was accessing it. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but in the shorter term that should do the trick.